# Add new table and references to it in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys, migration

Say I have a table `posts`, and I want to group them together. For this I want to create a new table `groups`, with `posts` having a fk to `groups`. The production db is already populated with many `posts` and each post should belong to its own group to begin with (post 1 belongs to group 1, which should be created, post 2 should belong to group 2, which should be created, etc)

So far I've come up with this solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to achieve this:

```rb
class AddGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    create_table :groups do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_reference :posts, :group, index: true

    Post.all.each { |post| 
      g = Group.create
      post.group_id = g.id
      post.save
    }

    change_column_null :posts, :group_id, false
  end


  def down
    remove_reference :posts, :group, index: true, null: false
    drop_table :groups
  end
end
```

Moreover, how do I test if the `down` method is correct?

Comment: This should work -- though I would break it up into 3 migrations for clarity and ease of down execution: 1) create groups table; 2) update posts table with new reference and set group id for existing posts; 3) change the posts group_id to not null

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the migrate and rollback options on your local environment.

```
bin/rails db:migrate
bin/rails db:rollback step=1 # if it is the latest migration
```

Answer (score 0):

For test the `down` method you can get a production database mysql dump, create a test db locally and upload the script, so you can test the migration with real data.

For the groups creation, if you want create Group entity with null values is ok, otherwise you must put the value inside the group's create method

```
Post.all.each { |post| 
      g = Group.create(param1: value1, param2: value2)
      post.group_id = g.id
      post.save
    }
```